# DRF DataTables GET Request Is Too Long

Tags: django, datatables, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF to serialize a model, and serve the model to an endpoint. I am using django-rest-framework-datatables to format that endpoint into the JSON DataTables requires with `?format=datatables`. I have a large DataTable that I am trying to render, and once I get to a certain number of columns, a nondescript 404 error occurs (https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7). The request URL for the ajax data is 2k+ characters long, and I think this is the issue since it's a GET request.

My query string looks like this:

```
format=datatables&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=triggerDate&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=entities&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=entities.entityDescription&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=analyticCategory&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=analyticCategory.analyticCategory&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=analytic&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=analytic.analyticDescription&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=risk&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=risk.risk&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=logic&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=logic.logic&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=description&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=disposition&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1554909043682
```

If I remove one column (any column), it works perfectly.

How do I get around this limitation without using POST since it's a REST API?

Comment: Seems like this limiting has various parties, including the browser used. You can control your server's limits but not sure if you can do much for browser limits

Comment: It seems to be limited in both Chrome and Firefox - which is odd, because it is't even that large. But...bingo...your comment about the server made me check the limits for IIS - and it's 2,048 characters for a query string. Thank you!